# How to intergrate facebook login in spring project

Tags: spring, facebook-javascript-sdk

hi I'm beginner of spring framework.
I'm trying to add social login in my spring project
I have followed face book API guide line, 
but it do not work 
I don't even know what problem is
please let me know solution for this
below is my code

thank you in advance

```
    <div class="modal-body login-modal">

            <p>Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required</p>
            <br/>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div id='social-icons-conatainer'>
                <div class='modal-body-left'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter your name" value="" class="form-control login-field">
                        <i class="fa fa-user login-field-icon"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" id="login-pass" placeholder="Password" value="" class="form-control login-field">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock login-field-icon"></i>
                    </div>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success modal-login-btn">Login</a>
                    <!-- <a href="#" class="login-link text-center">Lost your password?</a> -->
                </div>

                <div class='modal-body-right'>
                    <div class="modal-social-icons">
                        <a href="" class="btn facebook btn-default" id="facebook"> <i class="fa fa-facebook modal-icons"></i> Sign In with Facebook </a>
                        <a href='#' class="btn twitter btn-default" id="twitter"> <i class="fa fa-twitter modal-icons"></i> Sign In with Twitter </a>
                        <a href='#' class="btn google btn-default " id="google"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus modal-icons"></i> Sign In with Google </a>
                        <a href='#' class="btn linkedin btn-default" id="linkedin"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin modal-icons"></i> Sign In with Linkedin </a>
                    </div>

                </div>  
                <div id='center-line'> OR </div>
            </div>                                                                                                              
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <div class="form-group modal-register-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default"> New User Please Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
            iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
            icons: {
             rightIcon: ''
         }
        });

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //페이스북 로그인 버튼 이벤트 -> 로그인 대화 상자 호출
      $('#facebook').on('click',function(){
          function statusChangeCallback(response){ // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
              console.log('statusChangeCallback');
              console.log('response : ' + response);
              if(response.status === 'connected'){ // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
                  testAPI();
              } else {
                  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '어서오세요';
              }
          }
      });


      // sdk load, initialize it
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{918527135234800}',
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : '{v6.0}'
        });
        //
          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if(response.status === 'connected'){
                  // Logged into webpage & facebook
                  getUserData();
              }else{
                  //user is not authorized
              }
          });
      };
  //javascript sdk
      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    function testAPI(){
        console.log('testAPI worked, welcome!');
        FB.api('/me', function(response){
            console.log(response.name + '으로 페이스북 로그인');
            document.getElementById('login-status').innerHTML = response.name +'님, 안녕하세요.'
             //window.location.replace("http://" + window.location.hostname 
                     //+ ( (location.port==""||location.port==undefined)?"":":" + location.port) 
                     //+ "/users/index?facebookname="+facebookname);
        });
    }
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: You can use the project https://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, no need to copy it from the site to lose the structure.
https://www.baeldung.com/facebook-authentication-with-spring-security-and-social